# Cannot set value to Dictionary Key

Tags: c#

I fall in a weird situation, so essentially I need to create a `Dictionary` with a string as `Key` and a custom object as `Value`. The `Dictionary` have this implementation:

```
public static Dictionary<string, ForecastType> FullTime
{
    get
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, ForecastType>()
        {
            { "1", new ForecastType { Type = SignType.PartialFinal, Sign = Signs.HomeHomePF } },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see the key is `1` and the value is a custom class called `ForecastType`:

```
public class ForecastType : ViewModel
{
    private double _value;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Signs Sign { get; set; }
    public SignType Type { get; set; }
}
```

the property `Sign` and `Type` don't need an explaination, it's only an implementation of an `Enum`.
The property `Value` instead, cause me a lot of headache. In particular I can't set the value to this property, each value that I assign I get `0`.

I also implemented the `ViewModel`, I though to an issue related on `PropertyChanged`, but even this hasn't fixed the situation.

I valorize the `Value` property in this way:

```
FullTime["1"].Value = 5;
```

Note that the `OnPropertyChanged()` is called correctly, and the `value` inside it is `5`, but when I set a breakpoint, later the `FullTime["1"]..` line I get as `.Value` "0".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help. Best regards.

Comment: Because your FullTime property returns a new dictionary in the get, any changes you make to it will fail to persist as the object is recreated every time you call it.

Comment: @JonathonChase oh, that's right, good eye! But unfortunately I need to return a `Dictionary` from that property

Comment: Create a new Dictionary in the constructor, then return that via `get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the getter for the `FullTime` property return a new dictionary, you can, as of C# 6, provide a default value for the property like so:

```
public static Dictionary<string, ForecastType> FullTime {get;} = new Dictionary<string, ForecastType> () { /* initial dictionary values go here */ };
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `FullTime` property itself.  It *always* returns a *new* dictionary:

```
get
{
    return new Dictionary<string, ForecastType>() {...};
}
```

Every time you call it, whether to set or get anything *in* that dictionary, you're always getting a brand new dictionary.  No dictionary is ever persisted in memory.

Save an instance in the class and return *that* instance instead.  Perhaps something like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, ForecastType> _myDict;

public static Dictionary<string, ForecastType> FullTime
{
    get
    {
        if (_myDict == null)
            _myDict = new Dictionary<string, ForecastType>() {...};
        return _myDict;
    }
}
```

This way it will be initialized the first time you call that property, and any subsequent calls to that property will yield the previously initialized dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FullTime` has only a getter, which whenever is called returns a **new** dictionary with the default value of `ForecastType.Value`. One possible solution it would be the following:

```
public static Dictionary<string, ForecastType> FullTime { get; } = 
    new Dictionary<string, ForecastType>
    {
        { "1", new ForecastType 
            { 
                Type = SignType.PartialFinal, 
                Sign = Signs.HomeHomePF 
            } 
        // ...
    };
```

The difference is that now you have create a property with only a getter *but with a default value*, which cannot be changed. This value is a reference to a dictionary `Dictionary<string, ForecastType>`. Whenever you read the value of this property you would get the same reference but now you could mutate the state of the object that this reference points to, by adding new items to the dictionary, changing values etc.